# Dynamically adding events to a ASP.Net Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add an event and to fire this event from my controller class in ASP.Net for a Repeater which is added dynamically via a user control. The repeater control is exposed as a property and so I can reach its properties, etc.

What I do not know how to do is to invoke the events which will then add then add the rows that I want to show in the repeater.

Can anyone please help???

Below is a code snippet of how I am adding the usercontrol. The CreateRepeaterControl is where I am passing the usercontrol with the repeater exposed as a property. I can set the datasource and the headers, no problem! All I want to do is when the rows are added I want to do some further processing on them by adding some additional user controls.

Thanks

```
foreach(string name in teams)
{
    usercontrolTeams = setTeams = (usercontrolTeams)currentPage.LoadControl("gridLayout.ascx");
    setTeams.TeamName.Text = name;
    this.CreateRepeaterControls(setTeams);
    this.Report.ReportCollection.Controls.Add(setTeams);
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you please add the code you have?

Comment: I have added some more information

Comment: Do you call DataBind() on the repeater after setting the data source? Do you want to handle the OnItemDatabound event? Can you show the code of CreateRepeaterControl?

Comment: Yes, on the CreateRepeaterControl is where I set DataSource and DataBind(). Yes it is the ItemDataBound I want to handle. As a thought, because I am following a 3 tier design pattern, if I created an interface for the usercontrol in order to add in my controller and factory, to then call a method on the controller, would the view (i.e. the user control) be null at first because it is added dynamically, or would be still work after it has been added. If it will work, would work for each dynamically added repeater?

Comment: From my experience, I'd try to reduce the use of dynamically loaded controls to the spots that absolutely can't be solved in another way as it is very complex to really handle them correctly. Maybe you can first find a solution without user controls on a single page and split the parts later. The foreach-loop in your sample points in the direction that you could also add a Repeater to the page, place the UserControl (or their content) in the item and bind the Repeater to the names. You can bind the inner repeater in ItemDataBound of the outer Repeater. This way it's easy to add event handlers.